# React-native : Dynamically update header title in stack navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have made a custom component for header title(stack navigator)which shows user name along with some image.
On this page I have to edit the username and on success **Update it in header as well**

So my question is **How to change/update title dynamically?**

Comment: For React Navigation 5.x refer -
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62080817/dynamically-change-header-title-on-react-navigation-5-x

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This can be done using the navigation props.

You can use `this.props.navigation.state.params` in a component to set a new property. Call:

```
navigation.setParams({ param: value })
```

See [the documentation on headers](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/headers.html#updating-navigationoptions-with-setparams) for more detail.

Comment: @mehulmpt Sorry about that, they changed the docs. I updated it.

Comment: With react 5.0 or above you can simply do `this.props.navigation.setOptions({title: newTitle})`

Comment: @KewalShah it's actually:
 `props.navigation.setOptions({ headerTitle: newTitle, });` currently

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73502663/8238512

Answer (score 39):

For React Navigation version 1.x, 2.x, 3.x and 4.x, you can simply change the header by using the method shown in the code below, or the one in the original documentation: [React Navigation - using params in the title](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/headers.html#using-params-in-the-title)

```jsx
     static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
        const edit = navigation.getParam('edit', false);
        if(edit){
          return {
            headerTitle: 'Edit Page',
          };
        }else{
          return {
            headerTitle: 'Normal Page',
          };
        }
     };
```

For version 5.x and above, you may refer to the code below. Here are the links for the [official documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/headers/#using-params-in-the-title) and [example in expo](https://snack.expo.io/?platform=android&name=params%20in%20title&dependencies=%40react-native-community%2Fmasked-view%40%5E0.1.7%2C%40react-navigation%2Fbottom-tabs%40%5E5.7.0%2C%40react-navigation%2Fdrawer%40%5E5.8.5%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-bottom-tabs%40%5E5.2.13%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-top-tabs%40%5E5.2.13%2C%40react-navigation%2Fnative%40%5E5.7.0%2C%40react-navigation%2Fstack%40%5E5.7.0%2Creact-native-paper%40%5E3.10.1%2Creact-native-reanimated%40%5E1.7.0%2Creact-native-safe-area-context%40%5E3.0.2%2Creact-native-screens%40%5E2.9.0%2Creact-native-tab-view%40%5E2.14.0&sourceUrl=https%3A%2F%2Freactnavigation.org%2Fexamples%2F5.x%2Fparams-in-title.js).

```jsx
 import * as React from 'react';
    import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
    import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
    import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

    function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
          <Text>Home Screen</Text>
          <Button
            title="Go to Profile"
            onPress={() =>
              navigation.navigate('Profile', { name: 'Custom profile header' })
            }
          />
        </View>
      );
    }
    
    function ProfileScreen({ navigation }) {
      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
          <Text>Profile screen</Text>
          <Button title="Go back" onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} />
        </View>
      );
    }
    
    const Stack = createStackNavigator();
    
    function App() {
      return (
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen
              name="Home"
              component={HomeScreen}
              options={{ title: 'My home' }}
            />
            <Stack.Screen
              name="Profile"
              component={ProfileScreen}
              options={({ route }) => ({ title: route.params.name })}
            />
          </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

Comment: How to change the header title dynamically on react navigation 5.x

Comment: @Rizwan I have added the example for version 5.x

Comment: Any suggestion how can we do it in class component? I am able to show the headerRight using this.props.navigation.setOptions but onPress doesn't trigger the class component.

Comment: React navigation version 5.x
https://stackoverflow.com/a/73502663/8238512

Answer (score 35):

In **React 5.0 or above** you could do the following if you want to use a Class Component:

```
 componentDidMount() {
   this.props.navigation.setOptions({
     title: `Your Updated Title`,
   })
 }
```

Comment: this is the best one, this did what I needed easily

Comment: I have an issue working with this solution, I used useRoute to pass the objects as params to my app's detail screen but when I use code above or in general adding option and using it in app.js for some reason it wont work also not sure how to pass route params to the app.js.
Sorry if it looks dumb kindda new to the react and programming

Answer (score 24):

With **React Navigation 5** and **React Navigation 6** you can do this like this,
**set Params** in your component

```
props.navigation.navigate("ProductDetailScreen", {
      productId: itemData.item.id,
      productTitle: itemData.item.title,
    });
```

And display it

```
<Stack.Screen
      name="ProductDetailScreen"
      component={ProductDetailScreen}
      options={({ route }) => ({ title: route.params.productTitle })} // what 
need to add
/>
```

**or** you can do this in your component with `useEffect` hooks

```
useEffect(() => {
    props.navigation.setOptions({
      title: productTitle,
    });
  }, [productTitle, props.navigation]);
```

Comment: I tried last one and it works great! thanks

Answer (score 13):

```
 navigation.setOptions({ title: 'Updated!' })
```

[Reference](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/headers/#updating-options-with-setoptions).

Comment: Perfect answer.

Comment: For me I need headerTitle.   `navigation.setOptions({ headerTitle: "Updated!" });`

Answer (score 4):

the code that shows in the part below is for the version of react-navigation 2.x

you can try the following:

in my case I have the configuration of navigation in a file called, app-navigator.js

```
const ChatStackNavigator = createStackNavigator(
    {
        People: ListPeopleScreen, // People Screen,
        Screen2: Screen2
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'People'
        navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
            header: <AppBar title={navigation.getParam('appBar', {title: ''}).title}/>
        }),
        cardStyle: {
            backgroundColor: 'white'
        }
    }
);
```

The screen file would be as follows:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {List, ListItem} from 'react-native-elements';

class ListPeopleScreen extends Component {

    list = [
        {
            name: 'Amy Farha',
            avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/ladylexy/128.jpg',
            subtitle: 'Vice President'
        },
        {
            name: 'Chris Jackson',
            avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
            subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
        }
    ];

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.navigation.setParams({
            appBar: {
                title: 'Clientes'
            }
        });
    }

    render() {
        return <List
            containerStyle={{marginBottom: 30}}
        >
            {
                this.list.map((item) => (
                    <ListItem
                        roundAvatar
                        avatar={{uri: item.avatar_url}}
                        key={item.name}
                        title={item.name}
                    />
                ))
            }
        </List>
    };
}

export default connect(null)(ListPeopleScreen);
```

NOTE: in my case I am using redux, and the library of components [react-native-elements](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/0.19.1/lists.html)

Answer (score 3):

In version 3.x and 4.x this can be done using static navigationOptions function,

For class compenents,

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
    return {
      title: navigation.getParam('title', 'Fallback title');
    };
  }

  updateHeader = () => {
    // dynamically update header
    navigation.setParams({title: 'MyComponent'});
  }

  render() {
    // call updateHeader on click of any component
  }
}
```

For functional components,

```
const MyComponent = (props) => {
  const updateHeader = () => {
    // dynamically update header
    navigation.setParams({title: 'MyComponent'});
  }

  // call updateHeader on click of any component
}

MyComponent.navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
  title: navigation.getParam('title', 'Fallback title'),
})
```

Answer (score 2):

for react navigation Version: 5.x

```
   const ProductDetailScreen = props => {
       const { productId } = props.route.params;
       const { productTitle } = props.route.params;

       props.navigation.setOptions({ title: productTitle });

       return  (
            <View>
                <Text>{productId}</Text>
            </View>
        );
     };
```

for react navigation Version: 5.x

Comment: We get a warning for this, cannot update a component from inside the function body of a different component.

Answer (score 1):

For version 4, this is work for me.

```
    const HistoryScreen: NavigationStackScreenComponent<any, any> = (props) => {
  const { navigation } = props;

  useEffect(() => {
    let device = props.navigation.getParam("device");
    if(device) {
        navigation.setParams({title: `History - ${device.name}`})
    }
  }, []);

    ... render view

    HistoryScreen.navigationOptions = ({
      navigationOptions,
      navigation,
    }) => ({
      headerTitle: navigation.getParam("title") ? navigation.getParam("title") : "History"
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="OrdersScreen"
          component={OrdersScreen}
          options={{ title: 'My Orders' }}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For React-Navigation v3, I used the following command to change the title of a stack:

Class component:

```
this.props.navigation.setParams({ title: res.title });
```

Function component:

```
props.navigation.setParams({ title: res.title });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use createStackNavigator you can do like this:

```
createStackNavigator({
  // For each screen that you can navigate to, create a new entry like this:
  Profile: {
    // `ProfileScreen` is a React component that will be the main content of the screen.
    screen: ProfileScreen,
    // When `ProfileScreen` is loaded by the StackNavigator, it will be given a `navigation` prop.

    // Optional: When deep linking or using react-navigation in a web app, this path is used:
    path: 'people/:name',
    // The action and route params are extracted from the path.

    // Optional: Override the `navigationOptions` for the screen
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: `${navigation.state.params.name}'s Profile'`,
    }),
  },

  ...MyOtherRoutes,
});
```

from the [doc](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/stack-navigator)

call it like this:

```
navigation.navigate('Profile', {_id: item._id, name: item.screenName})}
```