# Dynamically change page title in React mobile app

Tags: react-native

Our React-baseed mobile app needs to change the page title after returning from a subpage. The initial title is set like this

```
static createRoute = (route: Route): Route => {
    let result = { ...route };
    result.title = (route.props as any).location.name as string;
    return result;
}
```

*mapStateToProps* and *render* are called with the new location.name in their props, but I can't see how to then change the title that appears in the navigation bar of the app.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46202481/186212) I should use *this.props.navigation* but my props never has a 'navigation' property. It does have a 'route' but it's ready-only.

Comment: what navigation lib did you used? `this.props.navigation` is for [React Navigation](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation)

Comment: Hard to tell. This got handed to us as a complete app and I'm now digging through it to make updates. I hoped the createRoute code would help identify which ever one it is

Comment: take a look at `package.json` and see `"dependencies"`, you can see all lib installed in your project

Comment: probably this one onsenui-react-redux-navigator

Comment: never heard about [those lib](https://github.com/karlvr/onsenui-react-redux-navigator) ):