# Dynamically change header title on react navigation 5.x

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I have recently updated my project to react navigation 5.x. 
In earlier version we used to set header title as follows :

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
        title: 'find',
});
```

This is not working on React Navigation 5.x.
Please Suggest.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do it via 2 methods;

1: Set `options` to be a variable from your screen and keep your current code:

```
<Stack.Screen
  name="Label"
  component={Component}
  options={Component.navigationOptions}
/>

// component
static navigationOptions = {
  title: 'find',
};
```

2: By using `setOptions` in your component:

```
<Stack.Screen
  name="News"
  component={News}
  options={{
    title: 'Default',
  }}
/>

// component
this.props.navigation.setOptions({title: 'find'});
```

Answer (score 1):

After going through various SO posts and documents I found the following ways to do this -

**In the Component using setOptions**

```
this.props.navigation.setOptions({title: 'TitleSetInComponent'});
```

Can also give a default title in `createStackNavigator();`

```
<Stack.Screen
  name="myComponent"
  component={MyComponent}
  options={{
    title: 'TitleSetInStackNavigator',
  }}
/>
```

**In** `createStackNavigator();` **using** `navigationOptions`  **as** `options`

```
<Stack.Screen
name="myComponent"
component={MyComponent}
options={MyComponent.navigationOptions}
/>

// MyComponent
static navigationOptions = {
title: 'TitleSetInComponent',
};
```

Comment: How is this different from my answer?

Comment: @AbdulSadikYalcin - Yes you are right, both are similar since yours was an earlier reply. I am marking yours as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you should definitly check out this: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen-options-resolution/

Here you can see how to set the title for each tab and each stack. Read threw the page and look at this func:

```
function getHeaderTitle(route) {
  // Access the tab navigator's state using `route.state`
  const routeName = route.state
    ? // Get the currently active route name in the tab navigator
      route.state.routes[route.state.index].name
    : // If state doesn't exist, we need to default to `screen` param if available, or the initial screen
      // In our case, it's "Feed" as that's the first screen inside the navigator
      route.params?.screen || 'Feed';

  switch (routeName) {
    case 'Feed':
      return 'News feed';
    case 'Profile':
      return 'My profile';
    case 'Account':
      return 'My account';
  }
}
```